# If I have a dictionary, how can I create another dictionary that inverts keys and values but places keys in an array? (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary:

```
dict = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'a'}
```

Is there an efficient way to invert the dictionary such that keys with identical values are grouped together?

The output should be:

```
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': [3]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with a `list` as default value.

This creates a list for new keys and you can append to it immediately:

```
from collections import defaultdict

original = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'a'}

flipped = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in original:
    flipped[value].append(key)
```